# Master project - Maven dependencies in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jboss

I'm currently working with Intellij as IDE, and I have 4 projects: 
- An Admin project (contains java & ember for the front-end)
- An WS project (contains the WS)
- An API project (contains the objects, dao's etc)
- A master project which only contains a pom to reference the other 3.

Admin and WS depend on API.

I deploy everything in JBoss. Maven clean-install works, but I can't deploy to jboss: I get a ClassNotFoundError: WS can't find classes in API

My pom of the master file looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>API</groupId>
        <artifactId>API</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:/.../api/target/API-1.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>WS</groupId>
        <artifactId>WS</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:/.../ws/www/target/WS-1.0.war</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Admin</groupId>
        <artifactId>Admin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:/.../admin/www/target/Admin-1.0.war</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I use Maven 3.3.3 and Jboss WildFly 8.2.1

In *Project Settings* I've simply put the 3 Maven libraries (Admin, WS, API) under

In the Deployement tab of the Jboss condfiguration, the 2 wars (Admin, WS) and the jar (API) are listed

The errors I get:

- Failed to define class ...ws.endpoints.helpers.WS in Module "deployment.WS-1.0.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link .../ws/endpoints/helpers/WS (Module "deployment.WS-1.0.war:main" from Service Module Loader) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: .../dao/helpers/Dao Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ...dao.helpers.Dao from [Module "deployment.WS-1.0.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to deploy all this?
I've also tried to use the local Maven repository to find the correct depedencies (removed the scope and system path), but I can't find them, although they are correct located under the C:\users.m2 directory

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying scope as 'system' means that your artifact is always available and is not looked up in a repository, so if you are building those artifacts during your build life cycle - "system" scope is not the right way to go. 
I would recommend: 
1. Try packaging your artifacts and deploy to JBoss manually, just to make sure that it works
2. Then try it out with Maven plugin for JBoss: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/examples/deployment-example.html